# Dimension of tracefree matrix subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ be an invertible matrix.

Find the dimension of the following subspace:

$$L = \{ X \in M_n(\Bbb R)|  tr(PX)=0\}$$

Don't know where to start. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map
$f:X \rightarrow tr(PX)$ is linear from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Your subspace $L$ is the kernel of $f$.
Since the image of $f$ has dimension 1 (take for example $X=P^{-1}$ to see that $f\neq0$).

You deduce that $\mathrm{dim}(L)=\mathrm{dim}(M_n(\mathbb{R}))-\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{R})=n^2-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The primary observation in this problem is that $tr(PX) = \sum_{1\le i, j \le n} P_{ij}X_{ij}$, which is same as the dot product in the case of vectors. The dimension of the vector space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is $n^2$. We need to find the dimension of the subspace which is perpendicular to $P$ (since the $dot$ product is zero). By drawing an analogy with vectors, its easy to see that the dimension of the subspace is $n^2-1$.